# What's the difference between 'checked' and (ngModel)

Tags: angular, ionic4

So I have inherited a project that was incompletely ported from ionic3 to ionic4. When updating some `<ion-checkbox>` instances I have had to change:

```
  <ion-checkbox 
    checked="selected.get(request.id)" 
    (click)="selectItem(request.id)" 
    color="tertiary" 
    slot="start"
  >
```

to:

```
  <ion-checkbox 
    (ngModel)="selected.get(request.id)" 
    (click)="selectItem(request.id)" 
    color="tertiary" 
    slot="start"
  >
```

To get it to toggle correctly. The use of `checked` caused it to misfire on the first click every time, and for the value to be inverted from that point forward.

What exactly is `(ngModel)` doing in this case? This is basically an undocumented feature shown in the [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/checkbox) without explanation or sample use...

Note that `selected` is a `Map<number, boolean>` and usage of that bool value elsewhere in the same view is working as expected.

Edit: I know the difference between an HTML property and the ng data model, I am just unclear about how the mechanism is working here...

Comment: The two are different things. checked is a default html attribute. And ngModel used for storing data into model.

Comment: But how does `(ngModel)` know which property to resolve to, for lack of a better word? I've been pouring over https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel without much luck...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a high level, `checked` belongs to HTML while `ngModel` belongs to Angular.

**[checked]**

`checked` is an HTML attribute for a checkbox and in angular, you can use the below code to set the checked property of a checkbox.

```
[checked]="item.checked"
```

**[(ngModel)]**

`[(ngModel)]` is an Angular property used for two way binding, meaning whatever change you make in the `.ts` file will reflect in your view and the other way as well. [More info](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

```
[(ngModel)]="item.checked"
```

Now, when do you use these? `[checked]` is used when if your requirement is just to set the checked property of the element, while you use `[(ngModel)]` to bind the element value to a variable in your `.ts` file so that you can access it for your logic behind.

Comment: Great, thanks. The note about `[checked]` is really what I was looking for. I still am not clear about how Angular knows which attribute to set to the state datum that I am providing. I guess I have some reading to do...

Comment: How does the compiler know to resolve `(ngModel)` to the `checked` attribute of the outer `<ion-checkbox>` element? 

(Please note that I have moved to the `[checked]` solution in the code.)